# How to set available/unavailable dates in date webform component?

Tags: datetime

I have a webform with a **date** component.

Then the visitor is able to select a date in a popup calendar. So far so good.

I need to show available and unavailable dates in the calendar, then visitors only can select an available date. Look my capture:

[image]

I'm trying with the [availability_calendars](https://drupal.org/project/availability_calendars) which is a great modules. But I have 2 problems with it:

1) it is a 2 steps process, you choose the date in the calendar and then you are directed to the webform to fill the rest of information (name, phone,...)

2) the calendar allows the visitor to select 2 dates: Arrival and Departure dates. I only need one date.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You may want [Date Restrictions](https://drupal.org/project/date_restrictions) module. It restricts allowed values in date fields, and datepicker popup widget, based on several criteria.

The module is still under initial development but may fit your needs. In any case please submit an feature request in the modules' issue queue if there's some missing functionality you find useful.

Comment: @chefnelone , did you find a solution to this issue that you can share with us?